# can't connect mongoDB atlas to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

i'm successfully connecting my mongodb to a cluster in the mongoATlas but when i try to connect to heroku i get this error :

```
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 52.55.178.46:27017 closed
2020-03-29T22:14:32.041176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:22:11)
2020-03-29T22:14:32.041176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
2020-03-29T22:14:32.041178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
2020-03-29T22:14:32.041178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:10:4)
```

and this is my code for connecting to mongoDb:

```
const uri = 
  "mongodb+srv://theosadxen:newPassword@cluster0a5rdm.mongodb.net/auth";
  mongoose
 .connect(uri, {
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
   useNewUrlParser: true
 })
 .then(() => console.log("Connected to mongodb..."));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar problem, and the first thing to do is test the new connection* (mongodb+srv://theosadxen:newPassword@cluster0a5rdm.mongodb.net/auth), still running from your computer. If the connection is established, then try:

Make sure your IP is whitelisted. The easiest solution is add the "All IPs" whitelist of 0.0.0.0/0

Then change the user's password to the password suggested by mongodb (Autogenerate Secure Password)

Modify this in your application and make a new commit for heroku, to restart everything.
It worked for me, and I hope it helps you too.

*the end of URI is strange! Did you change something on this string?